# input system where the user inputs the array position of the object followed by a # to indiacte quantity but it gives me an error

Tags: java, string, parsing, tokenize, numberformatexception

Its a tuck shop program!

```
public void sale() {
        if (!ingredients.isEmpty()) {
            printFood();
            String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your choices seperatad by a # to indicate quantity");
            String[] choices = choice.split(" ");
            String[] ammounts = choice.split("#");
            for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                int foodPos = (Integer.parseInt(choices[i])) - 1;
                int ammount = Integer.parseInt(ammounts[i+1]);
                try {
                    foods.get(foodPos).sale(ammount);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ingredient does not exsist");
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5967772/

gives the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1#3"
>     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)

Answer (score 2):

You're splitting the same String twice, but Strings are immutable so you're getting back two different arrays while the original String stays the same. Therefore, if you have input like:

```
1#3 2#4
```

You splitting it with `(" ")` will yield:

```
1#3
2#4
```

Which you try to parse as an Integer later at this line:

```
int foodPos = (Integer.parseInt(choices[i])) - 1;
```

That is throwing a NumberFormatException. You need to re-split each individual array element with `("#")`, rather than the source String.